# IntelliJ debugger: set short value

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

I am using intelliJ idea for my project, and in my project I have a method with variables of type Short in it. Since there is no Short literal in Java, how am I suppose to edit these values on the fly (when I hit a break point)?

Comment: Can you just edit this short value?

Comment: @longhua No, there is only a "Set value" option, which accepts new input (i.e it doesn't let you edit the old)

Comment: What do you mean by type Short? An object whose type is `java.lang.Short`?

Comment: @longhua yes, that's what I mean

Comment: Then I don't know how you want to edit a short value? In my opinion, Java supports auto boxing for these primary types. We can just set it the new value - via `(short) 6`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a short value via explicit cast: `(short) 11`.
[image: Set short value]